# How do I catch an Error from a pageerror listener attached to a Puppeteer page?

Tags: javascript, async-await, event-handling, try-catch, puppeteer

I am writing a prerenderer using Puppeteer.

I am adding a feature that allows the user to toggle whether an error in the page being rendered should result in prerendering being stopped (by means of rejecting a promise when this occurs).

My problem is that I cannot catch the rejected promise.

Here is my code:

```js
async getMarkup(route) {
    const s = this.useHttps === true ? 's' : '';
    const url = `http${s}://localhost:${this.port}${route}`;
    const page = await this.browser.newPage();

    page.on('pageerror', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      reject(err);
    });

    try {
      await page.goto(url, {timeout: 60000});
      if (this.waitForElement !== null) {
        await page.waitForSelector(this.waitForElement, {timeout: 60000});
      }
      return await page.content();
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

I am testing this by calling it on a route with an intentional syntax error in the script.

The handler is attached, but I cannot catch the rejected promise. This is the (truncated) output:

```
[Error: TypeError: (intermediate value).noSuchMethod is not a function
    at window.onload (https://localhost:3005/error_in_js.html:19:41)]
(node:61704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: reject is not defined
    at Page.<anonymous> (/Users/andy/repos/ewh-open-source/spa-prerenderer/index.js:164:7)
    at Page.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Page._handleException (/Users/andy/repos/ewh-open-source/spa-prerenderer/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:526:10)
    at CDPSession.<anonymous> (/Users/andy/repos/ewh-open-source/spa-prerenderer/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:123:60)
    at CDPSession.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at CDPSession._onMessage (/Users/andy/repos/ewh-open-source/spa-prerenderer/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:200:12)
    at Connection._onMessage (/Users/andy/repos/ewh-open-source/spa-prerenderer/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:112:17)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/andy/repos/ewh-open-source/spa-prerenderer/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js:44:24)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/andy/repos/ewh-open-source/spa-prerenderer/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
```

I've experimented with a few different approaches, including wrapping the handler in a new promise, assigning it as an anonymous async function and then calling that, but that yielded similar results.

I'm guessing it's possible to do what I'm setting out to, but perhaps I'm coming at it from the wrong direction. Any help that can be offered would be gratefully received, in any case.

**Edit #1:**

If I switch the line `reject(err)` for `throw err`, a similar thing happens, though the output details less of the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`:

```
[Error: TypeError: (intermediate value).noSuchMethod is not a function
    at window.onload (https://localhost:3000/error_in_js.html:19:41)]
(node:16112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
(node:16112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16112) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: `reject` makes sense when you have a promise, I don't see any here. if you want to catch javascript errors within the webpage you can't catch it like this

Comment: Thanks for responding — I understood that any calls to methods prefixed with `async` implicitly return promises. In this case, though page is initially assigned and the event handler attached synchronously, the call from which the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` originates (`await page.goto(`) is called asynchronously, so returns a promise.

I've tried simply rethrowing the error too, though this yields a similar response (see my recently added edit #1 above).

Answer (score 0):

`resolve` or `reject` should be used inside a promise to have functionality (e.g. `Promise.resolve`). Additionally,

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
//and
new Promise((x, y) => setTimeout(x, 1000))
```

are the same, so you need to have a promise for `reject` to have a meaning.

After `catch`, you're throwing the error again. Unless you're catching it somewhere else outside of `getMarkup` you'll see the same warning.

```js
try {
    await page.goto(url, {timeout: 60000});
    if (this.waitForElement !== null)
        await page.waitForSelector(this.waitForElement, {timeout: 60000});
    return await page.content();
} catch (err) {
    //HERE
    console.error(err.message);
}
```

Finally, if the error is happening in the webpage's Javascript, I'll suggest using `window.onerror` event in the page. You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror).